# Deserialize array in JSON into class/object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to store `JSON` data into a class. I could deserialize  my other`JSON` string into class by: `var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResult>(myJSON);` before I got stuck with array.

```
    {
      \"Test\": [{
         \"FirstBool\":1, 
         \"aString\":\"hello\"
      }]
    }
```

---

This is my class for `JSON`:

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstBool")]
    public bool FirstBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }
}      

public class ResultObject
{
        [JsonProperty("Test")]
        public List<Test> Test { get; set; }
}
```

How I deserialize my non-array `JSON`:

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObject>(myJSON);
```

What changes do I need to make it work again?

Comment: Are you sure `FirstBool` should be a `bool`? It's an `int` in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer**

Your json string as I've noticed later contains object named `Test` which is basically an array of `object`s ( `object[]` ).

As you can see from the json string :

> { 
>       "Test": [{
>           "FirstBool" : 1,
>           "aString" : "hello"
>       }]
>    }

`[` means that json object begins an array type and `]` means that json object ended an array type.

`{` means that json object begins an object type and `}` means that json object ended an object type.

Which in your case will require to make kind of a custom deserializer using existing methods from `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

Example for the `Test` object could be :

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
// now your obj contains field named "Test" that is of type object[]
// to retrieve informations you have to select "Test" token
JToken testToken = obj.SelectToken("Test");
// your token contains now something like " [{ "FirstBool" : 1, "aString" : "hello" }]"
// which basically is an array
// meaning that you have to iterate through this
foreach(var child in token.Children())
{
    // and convert it to a Test object
    Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(child.ToString());
    // test now is fully deserialized object
}
```

Comment: By you recommendation, should I change `public List<Test> Test { get; set; }` **to** `public Test Test { get; set; }` as well?

Comment: @user7399041 Sorry my bad. I haven't read your sample json string. Now this should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the well explained edited answer :) Works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize it as a list:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(json);
```

...instead of a wrapper object.

Comment: Should I change `public List<Test> Test { get; set; }` **to** `public Test Test { get; set; }` as well?

Comment: You don't need the ResultObject at all! It's just a wrapper right now, let JsonConvert handle it for you.