# Deserialise JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a json object that looks like this:

```
[
    {"attributes": []},
    {"attribute_values": []},
    {"digital_assets": []},
    {"products": []},
]
```

So I thought if I created the following c# class, I could deserialise straight into it using newtonsofts `JsonConvert.Deserialize<ProductContainer>()`:

```
public class ProductContainer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attributes")]
    public AttributeEntity[] Attributes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attribute_values")]
    public AttributeValueEntity[] AttributeValues { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "digital_assets")]
    public DigitalAssetEntity[] DigitalAssets { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "products")]
    public ProductEntity[] Products { get; set; }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ProductContainer' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

I think it may be because my JSON is in the incorrect format.  What am I meant to change in order for this to work properly (either in the JSON file or in the C# class)

Comment: Your JSON is not an object, but an array. An object is delimited by `{` brakets.

Comment: I think you're trying to de-serialize an array into an object, try:  JsonConvert.Deserialize<ProductContainer[]>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your `Json` string it is an `array` of objects.
I described difference between those in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849358/deserialize-array-in-json-into-class-object/41849456#41849456) answer.

Problem is that yours contains a `Dictionary` type that contains `string` as a key and an `array` as a value.

In your case :

```
[
    {"attributes": []},
    {"attribute_values": []},
    {"digital_assets": []},
    {"products": []},
]
```

You have to first deserialize this to let's say `JObject[]` or `List<JObject>` :

```
var objects = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<JObject>>();
```

Then process each of these objects and find out the key value and assign the values or you can just change the first and last character of your Json object :

```
string newJsonString = "{" + oldJsonString.Substring(1, oldJsonString.Length - 2) + "}";
```

Which will return :

```
{
    {"attributes": []},
    {"attribute_values": []},
    {"digital_assets": []},
    {"products": []},
}
```

*small remark here*
This will still return an object which contains a key and value pair where the key is of type `string` and value is and `array` of something. But using the second method you can deserialize it using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, JObject>>();` and then deserialize each of these objects to correct type eg.:

```
var dictionaryResult = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, JObject>>();
meResultObject.Attributes = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<AttributeEntity>>(dictionaryResult["attributes"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deserialize the JSON string into your C# object you need to make it a JSON object (not an array):

```
{
    "attributes": [],
    "attribute_values": [],
    "digital_assets": [],
    "products": [],
}
```

If you need to keep the original JSON array than you are restricted in using a different structure for the deserialization, like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>(obj);
```